# Sending parameter error in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, parameters, thread-safety

I wrote the following code in c# and after a lot of tries I still face the same error in the commented line

> error message: "method name expected"

so please can you tell me the appropriate way to send the "tmp" variable for my LoadSpeceficSontrol function.
any help is appreciated in advance.

```
 private void AddBox()
    {
        Thread thread= new Thread(() => LoadControls());
        thread.Start();
    }

    delegate void LoadControlsCallback();

    private void LoadControls()
    {
        int Nu = int.Parse(PageNumber.Text);
        for (int i = (Nu - 1) * 100; i < Nu * 200 && i < MoviesList.Count; i++)
        {
            MovieControl tmp = new MovieControl(MoviesList[i]);
            if (tmp.InvokeRequired || MoviesFlowPanel.InvokeRequired)
            {
                LoadControlsCallback d = new LoadControlsCallback(LoadSpeceficControl, new object[] {tmp}); // error here
                this.Invoke(d);
            }
            else
            MoviesFlowPanel.Controls.Add(tmp);
        }
    }

    private void LoadSpeceficControl(MovieControl tmp)
    {
        MoviesFlowPanel.Controls.Add(tmp);   
    }
```

Code Version 2.0

```
private void AddBox()
{
    Thread thread= new Thread(() => LoadControls());
    thread.Start();
}

private void LoadControls()
{
    int Nu = int.Parse(PageNumber.Text);
    for (int i = (Nu - 1) * 100; i < Nu * 200 && i < MoviesList.Count; i++)
    {
        MovieControl tmp = new MovieControl(MoviesList[i]);
        if (tmp.InvokeRequired || MoviesFlowPanel.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { MoviesFlowPanel.Controls.Add(tmp); });
        }
        else 
        MoviesFlowPanel.Controls.Add(tmp);
        tmp = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me here?

Comment: `this.Invoke(d);` is invoke method part of your class

Comment: @RahulAgarwal that was a little bit mysterious, do you suggest any edits? how to fix this

Comment: let me take a look..

Comment: Use `asunc/await` and  `Task.Run` instead of raw threads and attempting to marshal calls to the UI thread with `Invoke`.

Comment: In any case *this* code doesn't make much sense - nothing runs in the background, everything is marshalled back to the UI thread. If you want to "speed up" UI loading, change the way your code works - *don't* create multiple controls, use the same controls to bind to different data items. Use paging to load only what can be shown in one screen at a time. All grids support data virtualization in one way or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
delegate void LoadControlsCallback(MovieControl tmp);

LoadControlsCallback d = LoadSpeceficControl;
d(tmp);
```

Comment: Thanks, the code runs but there is a small problem can you help me with that, it won't take more than 1 minute

Comment: Awesome. Please accept the answer if you feel it was the solution to your problem. What other issue are you having?

Comment: i have edited the code you can see version 2.0 up, so what my code does is to add movies controls to my flow layout panel, but it adds the same movie twice. how to fix this (note; I checked the list that contains the movies it's fine and before I used thread it worked normally). and lastly, do I need to stop the thread or anything else to free Ram. thanks a lot you were more than helpful to me!

Comment: what happened with the fix?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see when it is being added twice and why?

Comment: I did, it seems that the problem is caused by the invoke line!

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate definition of `LoadControlsCallback` should match signature. Like from how you using, it should look like:

```
delegate void LoadControlsCallback(Action<MovieControl> action, object[] objarray);
```